# iOS - The file "XXX-XXX..." couldn't be opened because there is no such file

Tags: ios, xcode

I am developing an iOS application and suddenly xcode shows this error. There isn't any error log in the console.
The app crash and when I use "Continue program execution" xcode button, the name of the file changes.
[image]

Thanks!!

Comment: remove this file and try it :0

Comment: I had the same problem. Just add your file in CopyBundleResources under the build phases tab

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried cleaning your build via Product -> Clean?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. My issue was that some outlet still points to nonexistent property. In the simulator it still shows the correct error (this class is not key value compliant for bla bla). On iPhone somehow the error message becomes this.

Answer (score 0):

Confirm whether you have added the files to project target. 
Clean your project and build again.